# MXMLC compiler missing filesystem library

Tags: actionscript-3

I've had not trouble until this point directly from MXMLC command line. While compiling Actionscript 3 code I ran into a dependency problem.

```
import flash.filesystem;
```

and I get

```
    Error: Definition flash:filesystem could not be found
```

There are another or two file-related libraries such as filestream. Where can I find these standard libraries and how might I add them to my MXMLC library PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the specific classes you are trying to use? If you want to import all of the classes in the `flash.filesystem` package you need a `*` at the end of that import statement. Otherwise you need to append the class name(s). Something like one of these:

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
```

or

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
```

The other thing that might be an issue is the values in your flex-config.XML (or air-config.xml) file that is part of the SDK. You might need to configure this to include the classes in the AIR sdk, etc.